# Print mailing address labels from a view

Tags: commerce

We have a site built with Drupal Commerce and are looking for a way to print address labels from a view

So far I have been able to make a grid view of addresses and use the printer friendly version module to create a print view, but i can't seem to get the CSS right to line up the labels correctly.

I have seen this module for Drupal 6 - http://drupal.org/project/mailing_label, but nothing for Drupal 7. I was wondering if someone had any insight.

Thanks.

Comment: The module is really simple, you can take a stab at porting it to 7.

Comment: OK, I will give it a shot and comment back, thanks!

Comment: I am working with the coder module now, and I have Drupal 7 recognizing the module, but I getting the message of Invalid display id mailing_1. Do you think that this module is compatible with Drupal Commerce and/or entities other than nodes?

Comment: There is a D7 version of the mailing-label module. But, it is a [sandbox project](http://drupal.org/sandbox/clydefrog/1328782).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our warehouse team needed the ability to print address labels on the Avery 5163 template for every Commerce Order that is set to the status as Pending

I consider this to be a jury rig more than a Drupalish answer, but it got us through just the same.

Here is how we did it.

We created a page with a table view that shows all orders that are pending.

We created a view of Commerce Profiles that showed only the customer addresses in a grid format.

We used the Printer, e-mail and PDF versions module to create printer friendly versions of the views Here is the module - http://drupal.org/project/print

We altered the print.css file in the modules folder so that the address labels lined up with the template. (Later we ended up adding print.css file in our theme to override the one in the module folder and protect it from updates – Here are the instructions on how to add a style sheet - http://drupal.org/node/171209)

We created an html button in the header of view of pending Commerce Orders. It linked to the print version of the address label view.  (you can add the word print before any relative url to get it’s print view)

We altered the browser settings of the guys at our warehouse to exclude all the extra information that comes when the browser prints – Here are some instructions – http://lifehacker.com/5603815/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-url-and-other-text-when-i-print-from-web-pages

We also altered the margins in the browser.

We will be looking for a better solution as time and money for work permits , but I thought that someone else might find our experience helpful